# Memory usage while using Transformer to write xml file (JAVA)

Tags: java, xml-serialization

My application is running in 32 bit JVM and has high memory consumption. It is running on Windows.

I am using Transformer class to write Doc document to a file, very simliar to what explained here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html

It appears that while calling the transform method, there is a steep memory usage (>100MB) increase. This happens only when trying to write a document that contains Asian characters (UTF8). The document is <100KB in size.

Due to the fact the application is close to the 2GB process address space, the application crashes for that memory allocation.

Is it a known behavior of the Transformer?
Is there any way to write a Document to a file without using the transformer so I could overcome the problem?

Thanks,
Saar

Comment: DOM libraries are designed to work in with everything in memory. You could use a more Stax/Streaming approach where you write to disk as you process the data.  This can use much less memory e.g. < 1 MB.

Comment: @Peter - thing is that the document is very small (<100KB) so I would not believe that using DOM is my problem. I see the memory increase is when the transformer starts, not while creating the Document object

Comment: Perhaps its creating lots of garbage when loading for the first time. I don't believe that the classes would retain all of this memory.

Comment: @Saar Can you post your code?  Maybe it will shed more light on the issue.  You're right, if the XML document is only 100KB, then the program shouldn't be throwing out-of-memory errors.  It's true that a DOM loads the entire XML document in memory, but a 100KB XML file shouldn't take up that much memory.